# How can I connect copper pipe to an unthreaded, galvanized pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, copper

I have a di-electric union which I want to install, but the union's galvinized side is threaded. The unthreaded, galvanized pipe is attached to the house so I can't easily thread it.

Perhaps there's some better way to connect an unthreaded 3/4" galvanizeded pipe to a 1/2" copper water line?

Comment: What are you wanting to run through the pipe?

Comment: It's a cold water line supplying my bathroom sink. The copper is supply and it meets the unthreaded, galavanized under the house in the crawl space. I'm wanting to connect the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 or more options. #1 get a shark bite to go from galvanized to copper. #2 You need to go to a plumbing store and get a galvanized nipple and then extend your copper to the point the pipe screws into a coupling or other fitting. #3 If you don't want to extend your copper get an exact measurement and have a new piece of pipe cut and threaded. #1 is the easiest way and may be the most expensive but what you save in time is worth it. I may have used a Dresser compression fitting [home depot calls them pattern](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Mueller-Global-3-4-in-Galvanized-Iron-Long-Pattern-Compression-Coupling-160-004HC/100155616) fittings for galvanized repair in the wall I could not thread or remove but thought it was a shark bite.

Comment: Thanks noting that there is sharkbite for galvanized. I thought it was only for copper.

Comment: Sharkbite is not designed to go over a unthreaded galvanized.

Comment: Is there anything I can put on unthreaded galvanized? Or am I going to need to thread it?

Comment: Couldn't you attach the dielectric directly to the compression fitting instead of a nipple? Or could you attach a reducing coupling to the compression fitting so that the dielectric can be attached without a nipple?

Comment: I can't find any sharkbite-style fittings for galvanized or black iron...